# Website location masking - how to hide where media is loaded from?

Tags: html, magento, ip

I'm not really sure how to even ask the question, let alone find an answer. Let me explain:

I have one website (http://www.foo.com). I own a domain that I configured as a URL frame so that when I open http://xyz.bar.com I see my Magento website at http://foo.com/xyz.
The thing is I want to completely hide all references to foo.com. This way I hide it in the address bar, but I still get it when hovering over links and while opening media, in the lower left corner. A simple right mouse click would also give it away.

I know I can configure my Magento website to show a specific base URL. I've tried looking for solutions, but I just don't have the vocabulary to find anything that helps. I appreciate any assistance.

*Edit: I understand that in order to post a question here one must know what one is talking about, but I'm stuck and I have no one to help me; so please take it easy with the negative reputation.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was already a different domain configured in the same server which is "mapped" to another folder. I simply copied the image files from /home/site1/pics to /home/website2/pics. When loading content from website2, I no longer see "loading from site1".

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

If the browser is expected to ask example.com for the resource, then you have to tell the browser about example.com. Anything you tell the browser you also tell the user.

The only way to make the data appear to come from example.org would be to copy it from example.com to example.org so it really would be coming from example.org.

HTTP redirects could hide the real URL … but only until it was followed, at which browser the browser is informed where the data really lives.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I don't deal with our company's hosting environment and the person that does is unavailable. Is there any way I can make it show the ip address of the source server, instead of foo.com? I mean show "loading 135.34.5.234/images/xyz.jpg"?

Comment: @Mike - that _might_ work. Ping the domain in question to get that IP, but bear in mind modern virtual hosting environments usually have (smaller) sites on non-default vhosts, which means that you need the domain name to access the website, and the raw IP will just point to a holding page.

Comment: @halfer I've tried changing "foo" with the IP address, but I just got a 403 error. I thought that there might be something missing after the IP, but what you said makes me lose a bit of the hope. I've been researching this on and off for a few weeks and it's really frustrating. I guess I have to leave this to a pro... Thank you

Comment: @Mike - it doesn't require a _pro_ as such, but it will require a bit of learning. You on shared hosting (cPanel _et al_) or VPS/dedi? However the description as to what to do is probably more involved than will fit in an answer here, and either needs a colleague or a consultant `:)`

Comment: @halfer: exactly. Plus, I wouldn't want to mess with the existing site's configuration too much. Unfortunately no colleagues here... Stackoverflow was my final option and even here I get negative points for asking :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the images through separate requests and store them in a temporary location. This will have a lot of overhead, so caching would be mandatory.

Another option is to grab all the images you need and store them permanently on your own server through a batch request.

It's not clear what your actual problem is, so we can't help further. (Why do you need to do this?) There might be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: The reason involves a corporate decision. Basically I need a way to host two websites on the same server and preventing the user from figuring out a connection between them. If we could save the money  it would be great, specially since this new website will only serve as a catalog and it will be accessed half a dozen times per day. We choose Magento since it needs to be updated with prices, products and stocks as frequently as possible, and that's the tool we work with. Would your solution be compatible with a magento installation?

Comment: Compatible, yes, but it would take development. It's actually easier than initially thought since you control both domains.